# boost.regex fails to link with MinGW and GCC compiler

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, boost, mingw

On Windows 10 I installed MinGW, and use Eclipse to write C++ programs together with Boost libraries 1.71.0  (for example boost/algorithm/string.hpp).
I can successfully create the executable using `boost::replace_all(doc, "@", "_");` in my source code.

The compiler is GCC version 8.2.0

As I also want use the Boost.regex library I built the Boost libraries suffing following commands commands in a Command Prompt window

```
bootstrap.bat

.\b2 --prefix=C:\Users\makkun\Documents\boost_1_71_0\build install
```

I then changed to the Boost root directory and invoked b2 as follows:

```
b2 --build-dir=C:\Users\makkun\Documents\boost_1_71_0\build toolset=gcc --build-type=complete stage
```

The directory `C:\Users\makkun\Documents\boost_1_71_0\stage\lib` was created and I can see the regex related files

```
libboost_regex-mgw82-mt-d-x32-1_71.a
libboost_regex-mgw82-mt-d-x32-1_71.dll.a
libboost_regex-mgw82-mt-sd-x32-1_71.a
libboost_regex-mgw82-mt-s-x32-1_71.a
libboost_regex-mgw82-mt-x32-1_71.a
libboost_regex-mgw82-mt-x32-1_71.dll.a
libboost_regex-mgw82-mt-d-x32-1_71.dll
libboost_regex-mgw82-mt-x32-1_71.dll
```

In Eclipse I added in MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries >  Library search path (-L) the library folder `"C:\Users\makkun\Documents\boost_1_71_0\stage\lib"`

In my source code I have

```
    #include <boost/regex.hpp>
    ...
    boost::regex e("(\\d{4}[- ]){3}\\d{4}");
```

The compilation is OK, but the linking with command

```
g++ "-LC:\\Users\\makkun\\Documents\\boost_1_71_0\\stage\\lib" "-LC:\\Users\\makkun\\Documents\\boost_1_71_0\\libs" -o LastDoc.exe "src\\LastDoc.o"
```

fails with 46 errors of the type undefined reference to:

```
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: src\LastDoc.o: in function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10710027cpp_regex_traits_char_layerIcEC2ERKNS0_21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEE':
    C:/Users/makkun/Documents/boost_1_71_0/boost/regex/v4/cpp_regex_traits.hpp:370: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107100::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: src\LastDoc.o: in function `ZN5boost16re_detail_10710011raw_storage6extendEj':
    C:/Users/makkun/Documents/boost_1_71_0/boost/regex/v4/regex_raw_buffer.hpp:131: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107100::raw_storage::resize(unsigned int)
...'
```

I also tried to add in MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries >  Libraries (-l) string "boost-regex" but the linker does find it

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_regex
```

Can anybody suggest where the problem is, please?

Comment: When you build your program you tell the linker where to search for libraries (with the `-L` option). But you never ask it to actually link with the Boost libraries, which is done with the `-l` (lower-case L) option.

Comment: How do I tell the linker to link with the Boost libraries, the option -lboost-regex failed. g++ "-LC:\\Users\\90100027\\Documents\\boost_1_71_0\\stage\\lib" "-LC:\\Users\\90100027\\Documents\\boost_1_71_0\\libs" -o LastDoc.exe "src\\LastDoc.o" -lboost_regex 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_regex

Comment: According to your list, the name of the non-debug library is `boost_regex-mgw82-mt-x32-1_71`. This is the library you need to link with.

Comment: Thank you @Some programmer dude. Following your suggestion I can now compile. How did you know I had to select exactly that file, please? Where I can find the meaning of the various -d-, -s- , -sd-, please?

Comment: The `d` is most likely for **d**ebug, that's easy to deduce. But you have to read the Boost documentation for the others.

Comment: I found their meaning, thank you.